# closure compile load module by demand

Tags: module, google-closure-compiler

I just find

```
 java -jar Build\Tools\compiler.jar ^ 
--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS ^ 
--externs Build\jQuery.externs.js ^ 
--js Build\Output\Compiling.js ^ 
--js Script/Themes.lang.js ^ 
--js Script/Themes.js ^ 
--module Core:3 ^ 
--js UI/ThemeChooser/ThemeChooser_en.htm.js ^ 
--js UI/ThemeChooser/ThemeChooser.js ^ 
--module UI_ThemeChooser:2:Core ^ 
--js UI/VerticalTabs/VerticalTabs_en.htm.js ^ 
--js UI/VerticalTabs/VerticalTabs.js ^ 
--module UI_VerticalTabs:2:Core ^ 
--js Pager/Pager_en.htm.js ^ 
--js Pager/jquery.Pager.js ^ 
--js Pager/Pager.js ^ 
--module Pager:3:VerticalTabs ^ 
--module_output_path_prefix .\Compiled\
```

but I want to know how to set the --closure_entry_point and how to load moduled js by demand

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

--closure_entry_point is used with --manage_closure_dependencies and --only_closure_dependencies to automatically trim files from the set pass to the compiler.  If you aren't using these options they have no value.

For you second question:

You can load your module the same way you would load any other javascript.  The simplest method is simply to append a script tag to the DOM when you want to load the module.  Another method is to use an XHR to load the js and then call eval() with the results.

Comment: I want to set closure library as my first module, myself js as the second module and depends first module, so I donnot need set --closure_entry_point?

Comment: No you don't need to set it.  Be aware though that in ADVANCED mode that the compiler will move source between modules, so you can't swap modules from compiles unless the entire set of input sources are identical. This is the effect of global optimizations.

Comment: Now I can compile to multiple js files, eg:A is defined in module1, in module2(deps on module1) I can new A, set A's field, But I cannot call A's function, I donnot know what's wrong, can you give me some suggeston?